# Jquery: Animate ScrollLeft by a certain amount

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

```
var xxx= 100px;

$(".scrollbutton").click(function () { 
    $('.selector').animate({scrollLeft:xxx)}, 500);
});
```

Now this scrolls to the specific position 100px from the start. How to phrase this such that every time the scrollbutton is clicked, it scrolls left by 100px?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var xxx= 100;

$(".scrollbutton").click(function () { 
    $('.selector').animate({scrollLeft:"+="+xxx)}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution:

```
var scrollLeftAmount = 100;
$('.scrollbutton').click(function () { 
    $('.selector').animate({
        scrollLeft:'+='+scrollLeftAmount
    },500);
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNvLu/2/

---

Based on the jQuery documentation for `.animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#basic-usage

> Animated properties can also be **relative**. If a value is supplied with a leading **+=** or **-=** sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by **adding** or **subtracting** the given number from the **current value** of the property.

Example:

> [...] left: "+=50", [...]